# Is NVP a better development option versus Net SDK for PayPal in an ASP.Net app?

Tags: paypal-nvp, paypal

I am new to developing with PayPal API.

I am needing to integrate an ASP.Net website with PayPal. I have read up on using NVP as well as PayPal Merchant Net SDK, but not sure if one is better than the other. While SDK offers intellisense which is good for developers, but may be NVP is faster since there is no extra layer between the website and PayPal.

**Question**: Is NVP a better way to go when integrating a website with PayPal as compared to a NET SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .Net SDK. The processing time difference is absolutely negligible if there is one at all.

And if you are using NVP you will have to handle/parse the request/response by your one, that's additional work and code therefore a potential source of errors.